# Razorpay not working in ionic 4 and android 7.0.0

Tags: ionic4, razorpay

I have created Ionic 4 application and integrated Razorpay. Razorpay callback is working fine in android version 7.1 or greater version. but when I using Razorpay in android version 7.0.0 frame opens but when i clicked on Success or Failure then it reload my whole application and not calling any callback.